# How to record random captcha value generated by selenium ide, which command i use

Tags: selenium

I record test in Selenium Ide but but in login page appears captcha. which command i use for handle captcha, Please help me

Comment: You obviously do not understand what CAPTCHA is.

Answer (score 2):

Captcha by definition CANNOT be automated, if it could then that would defeat it's object.

When automating a site with Captcha you will need to have some kind of configuration when running on Test such as always display the same value, accept any value, skip captcha, etc